# How to use where method to find all content id in array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the code below, "@search.sensors" is an array that has been searched. The sensors belong to a publication. Is there way to find Publication of each sensor in the array?

Publication Model

```
class Publication < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sensors, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
end
```

Sensor Model

```
class Sensor < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :publication
end
```

I tried this but it does not work

Search Model

```
@sensors = @search.sensors
@publications = Publication.joins(:sensors).where(id: params[@search.sensors.map(&:id)])
@publications.uniq
```

Comment: What does your `@search.sensors` function look like and why does it return an array instead of an `ActiveRecord` relation?

Comment: @jvillian is right. If it's an ActiveRecordRelation(which it should be imo) then you can just `select` or `pluck` the ids. `@search.sensors.pluck(:publication_id) or @search.sensors.select(:publication_id)`

Comment: @mikeheft - more like `Publication.joins(:sensors).where(sensors: {id: @search.sensors})`.

Answer (score 3):

If the `@search.sensors` resolves to an array of `Sensor` type, then you can easily do:

```
Publication.where(id: @search.sensors.map(&:publication_id))
```